# Unable to perform click on Katalon Studio

Tags: xpath, automation, click, katalon-studio

**Problem**
I am new to Katalon and Automation testing, I have tried everything but unable to perform click function for a simple button

My code doesn't fail either but the click function is not performed on page

**Webpage**
https://www.ratesupermarket.ca/term_life_insurance

**HTML**

```
<button class="cta-primary" id="submit" type="submit"> Get Quotes <i class="icon-entity" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
```

**xpath**

```
//button[@id='submit']
```

**Script-Code**

```
WebUI.openBrowser('')
'go to URL'
WebUI.navigateToUrl('https://www.ratesupermarket.ca/term_life_insurance')
'Enter Post code - Go to next Page'
WebUI.setText(findTestObject('Object Repository/Rates Page 1/Page_Life Insurance Comparison/input_postal_code'), 'M12W22')
WebUI.click(findTestObject('Object Repository/Rates Page 1/Page_Life Insurance Comparison/button_Get Quotes'))
```

**Console Log**

```
09-19-2018 12:58:17 PM - [START]  - Start Test Case : Test Cases/Perform click and Get Quote
09-19-2018 12:58:17 PM - [INFO]   - Evaluating variables for test case
09-19-2018 12:58:18 PM - [START]  - Start action : openBrowser
09-19-2018 12:58:18 PM - [INFO]   - Opening browser
09-19-2018 12:58:18 PM - [INFO]   - Starting 'IE' driver
09-19-2018 12:58:18 PM - [INFO]   - Action delay is set to 0 seconds
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
3.6.0.0
Listening on port 2893
Log level is set to TRACE
Log file is set to C:\Users\cnawork\AppData\Local\Temp\Katalon\Test Cases\Perform click and Get Quote\20180919_125813\IEDriverServer.log
Only local connections are allowed
Sep 19, 2018 12:58:21 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
09-19-2018 12:58:21 PM - [RUN_DATA] - Logging run data 'sessionId' with value '50bd252d-7549-4b1a-9a8c-d9fa80318749'
09-19-2018 12:58:21 PM - [RUN_DATA] - Logging run data 'browser' with value 'IE 11'
09-19-2018 12:58:21 PM - [RUN_DATA] - Logging run data 'platform' with value 'Windows 8.1'
09-19-2018 12:58:21 PM - [RUN_DATA] - Logging run data 'seleniumVersion' with value '3.7.1'
09-19-2018 12:58:21 PM - [RUN_DATA] - Logging run data 'proxyInformation' with value 'ProxyInformation{proxyOption=NO_PROXY, proxyServerType=HTTP, password=, proxyServerAddress=, proxyServerPort=0}'
09-19-2018 12:58:21 PM - [PASSED] - Browser is opened with url: ''
09-19-2018 12:58:21 PM - [END]    - End action : openBrowser
09-19-2018 12:58:21 PM - [START]  - Start action : navigateToUrl
09-19-2018 12:58:21 PM - [INFO]   - Checking url
09-19-2018 12:58:21 PM - [INFO]   - Navigating to 'https://www.ratesupermarket.ca/term_life_insurance'
09-19-2018 12:58:27 PM - [PASSED] - Navigate to 'https://www.ratesupermarket.ca/term_life_insurance' successfully
09-19-2018 12:58:27 PM - [END]    - End action : navigateToUrl
09-19-2018 12:58:27 PM - [START]  - Start action : setText
09-19-2018 12:58:27 PM - [INFO]   - Finding Test Object with id 'Object Repository/Rates Page 1/Page_Life Insurance Comparison/input_postal_code'
09-19-2018 12:58:27 PM - [INFO]   - Checking object
09-19-2018 12:58:27 PM - [INFO]   - Checking text
09-19-2018 12:58:27 PM - [INFO]   - Checking timeout
09-19-2018 12:58:27 PM - [INFO]   - Finding web element with id: 'Object Repository/Rates Page 1/Page_Life Insurance Comparison/input_postal_code' located by 'By.xpath: //input[@id='postal_code']' in '30' second(s)
09-19-2018 12:58:27 PM - [INFO]   - Found 1 web elements with id: 'Object Repository/Rates Page 1/Page_Life Insurance Comparison/input_postal_code' located by 'By.xpath: //input[@id='postal_code']' in '30' second(s)
09-19-2018 12:58:27 PM - [INFO]   - Clearing text of object 'Object Repository/Rates Page 1/Page_Life Insurance Comparison/input_postal_code'
09-19-2018 12:58:27 PM - [INFO]   - Checking timeout
09-19-2018 12:58:27 PM - [INFO]   - Finding web element with id: 'Object Repository/Rates Page 1/Page_Life Insurance Comparison/input_postal_code' located by 'By.xpath: //input[@id='postal_code']' in '30' second(s)
09-19-2018 12:58:27 PM - [INFO]   - Found 1 web elements with id: 'Object Repository/Rates Page 1/Page_Life Insurance Comparison/input_postal_code' located by 'By.xpath: //input[@id='postal_code']' in '30' second(s)
09-19-2018 12:58:27 PM - [INFO]   - Setting text of object 'Object Repository/Rates Page 1/Page_Life Insurance Comparison/input_postal_code' to value 'M12W22'
09-19-2018 12:58:27 PM - [PASSED] - Text 'M12W22' is set on object 'Object Repository/Rates Page 1/Page_Life Insurance Comparison/input_postal_code'
09-19-2018 12:58:27 PM - [END]    - End action : setText
09-19-2018 12:58:27 PM - [START]  - Start action : click
09-19-2018 12:58:27 PM - [INFO]   - Finding Test Object with id 'Object Repository/Rates Page 1/Page_Life Insurance Comparison/button_Get Quotes'
09-19-2018 12:58:27 PM - [INFO]   - Checking object
09-19-2018 12:58:27 PM - [INFO]   - Checking timeout
09-19-2018 12:58:27 PM - [INFO]   - Finding web element with id: 'Object Repository/Rates Page 1/Page_Life Insurance Comparison/button_Get Quotes' located by 'By.xpath: //button[@id='submit']' in '30' second(s)
09-19-2018 12:58:28 PM - [INFO]   - Found 1 web elements with id: 'Object Repository/Rates Page 1/Page_Life Insurance Comparison/button_Get Quotes' located by 'By.xpath: //button[@id='submit']' in '30' second(s)
09-19-2018 12:58:28 PM - [INFO]   - Clicking on object: 'Object Repository/Rates Page 1/Page_Life Insurance Comparison/button_Get Quotes'
09-19-2018 12:58:29 PM - [PASSED] - Object: 'Object Repository/Rates Page 1/Page_Life Insurance Comparison/button_Get Quotes' is clicked on
09-19-2018 12:58:29 PM - [END]    - End action : click
09-19-2018 12:58:29 PM - [PASSED] - Test Cases/Perform click and Get Quote
09-19-2018 12:58:29 PM - [END]    - End Test Case : Test Cases/Perform click and Get Quote
```

Comment: **HTML**  
<button class="cta-primary" id="submit" type="submit"> Get Quotes <i class="icon-entity" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>

Comment: Can you paste your log or console output? It will help us find the problem sooner.

Comment: Added console Log and Code details

Answer (score 1):

In katalon there is a WebUI Element called "wait for element visible". Use this element hopefully this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this keyword:

```
@Keyword
def clickUsingJS(TestObject to, int timeout)
{ 
    WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver()
    WebElement element = WebUICommonHelper.findWebElement(to, timeout)
    JavaScriptExecutor executor = ((driver)as  JavaScriptExecutor)
    executor.executeScript('arguments[0].click()',element)
}
```